# Как я могу повернуть Rectangle

Tags: c#

У меня есть `Rectangle`, который накладывается вторым слоем поверх изображения.

Я поворачиваю изображение на 90 градусов и должен одновременно с ним поставить на новое место Rectangle.

Как я могу вычислить новые координаты?

Comment: https://excel2.ru/sites/default/files/transform-6.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я немного поправил вопрос.

Comment: Что есть "новое место"?

Comment: @Igor то место куда должен встать прямоугольник после поворота изображения. Т.е скажем так, 2 слоя должны двигаться вместе. И вот мне нужно вычислить, куда нужно расположить Rectangle после поворота образа.